# sliding window function in julia

Tags: julia

I am looking to take a collection and slide a window of length 'w' and step size 's' over it to get many sub collections.

I have seen [Base.Iterators.partition](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/iterators/#Base.Iterators.partition) but that does not allow sliding by less than the window (or partition) length.

I have written something myself that works but I expect there is already a function that does this and I just haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming `z` is your `Vector` and `s` is your step size and `w` is window size simply do:

```
((@view z[i:i+w-1]) for i in 1:s:length(z)-w+1)
```

Example:

```
z = collect(1:10)
for e in ((@view z[i:i+4]) for i in 1:2:length(z)-4)
    #do something, try display(e)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I just found [IterTools.jl](https://juliacollections.github.io/IterTools.jl), it has a [partition](https://juliacollections.github.io/IterTools.jl/stable/#IterTools.partition) with custom step size.

```
julia> for i in partition(1:9, 3, 2)
           @show i
       end
i = (1, 2, 3)
i = (3, 4, 5)
i = (5, 6, 7)
i = (7, 8, 9)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [RollingFunctions](https://github.com/JeffreySarnoff/RollingFunctions.jl)? It seems to me that it does what you're looking for, it has `rolling` and `running` functions which take a function, a vector, and a windows size as input and return the result of applying the function over successive windows.

Comment: There's also https://github.com/JuliaImages/ImageFiltering.jl which is more general than the name seems to indicate

Comment: Thank you, the rolling functions look like a good fit. I'm surprised something like that isn't in the standard library yet. 

btw, @nils-gudat I gave you an upvote but I barely have any reputation yet so it may not show up

Comment: actually, after looking closer at [RollingFunctions.jl](https://github.com/JeffreySarnoff/RollingFunctions.jl), it doesn't appear to allow custom step size :/

Comment: What do you mean by custom step size?

Comment: Ah wait you mean calculate the rolling function only every `n` steps of your input vector? I guess you could just index the result like `rollmean(rand(100), 5)[1:n:end]`, although that's probably slightly inefficient as you compute all rolling means and then throw away all but `length(input)/n` of them

Comment: ImageFiltering supports this.

Comment: I see that ImageFiltering does not support even size of window, I wanter to have rolling function of window 3x20 and it complained that only odd window sizes are allowed.