# Getting 2-dimensional sliding windows from an image in Julia

Tags: image-processing, multidimensional-array, julia, sliding-window

I need to get several sliding windows from an image using the Julia programming language. I am newcomer to the language and having a hard-time finding a performant solution.

**The problem**: Lets say I have a grayscale image of size 2000x2000 pixels. I need to get/collect all possible windows (aka sub-arrays) of size 8x8 from this image. In NumPy (Python) with is done simply by `np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(img, (8,8))`. Where `img` is an array of shape 2000x2000 and the tuple (8,8) defines the window size is each dimension.

**What have I tried:** I have seen similar questions of SO before such as:

- [View on Julia array using sliding window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63769931/view-on-julia-array-using-sliding-window)
- [sliding window function in julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60886797/sliding-window-function-in-julia)

Unfortunately, I am not able to get these suggestions to work properly for my use case. For example the `mapwindow function` in **ImageFiltering.jl** doesn't support windows of even shape such as 8x8. Even calling the function with an explicit border parameter doesn't give the right result; `mapwindow(collect, img, (9,9), border=Inner())`.

**What I expect:** Given an array of 2000x2000 pixels, I need to return 1993x1993 (39,72,049) sub-arrays each of shape 8x8 pixels. There is no requirement of fancy stuff like padding or custom stepsize (this should simply be 1).

I have written a custom function (see below) that implements this but I don't want to reinvent the wheel since there should already be something pretty performant somewhere in Julia.

Thank you

```
function get_windows(img, window_size=8)
           X, Y = size(img)

           [img[i:i+window_size-1, j:j+window_size-1]
           for i in 1:X-window_size+1
           for j in 1:Y-window_size+1]
end
```

Comment: Did you try, for example: `mapwindow(mean, img, (-4:3, -4:3); border=Inner())` ? This does the 8x8 window you wanted, and applies the `mean` function on it.

Comment: In your hand-rolled `get_windows` function, you should probably put a `@view` in front of the `img[...]` to avoid allocating.

Comment: @DanGetz This works well but it gives me back the result in column-major format (which I understand is the default in Julia). Is there any way to get the windows back in a row-major manner?

Comment: @BallpointBen Good suggestion. I managed to significantly reduce the allocations.

Comment: row-major and column-major refers to the layout of an array in memory and to promote efficiency, the order of operations on windows. If the order of operations (or layout) is important for your processing then explain how. In general, it is better the processing is agnostic to these implementation details.

Comment: @DanGetz For the following 3x3 matrix [[1 2 3]; [4 5 6]; [7 8 9]] calling  `mapwindow(collect, A, (0:1, 0:1); border=Inner())` gives me 4 smaller-matrices (as expected). But the order of these small-matrices is not identical to my hand-rolled function `get_windows` above. For example the 1st matrix is the same for both approaches but the mapwindow produces [[4 5]; [7 8]] as the second small-matrix while get_windows produces [[2 3]; [5 6]] as the 2nd small-matrix.
In short mapwindow traverses down the column first before moving on to the rows. Can this behavior be reversed?

Comment: Yes, `get_windows` returns the windows in a different order, because of the order of iteration (`for i... for j...`) and window indexing. But although it may be the desired order, in this case, it is unnatural and corresponds to taking the 'natural' order and doing a transpose. To do things naturally, `get_windows` would need to use: `[img[i:i+window_size-1, j:j+window_size-1] for i in 1:X-window_size+1, j in 1:Y-window_size+1]` which returns a matrix and in the same order of `mapwindow`. `get_windows` currently doesn't return a matrix, any matrix can be vectorized using `vec(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work with ranges.
Consider this image 4x4:

```
julia> img = Gray.(i*j/20 for i in 1:4, j in 1:4)
4×4 Array{Gray{Float64},2} with eltype Gray{Float64}:
 Gray{Float64}(0.05)  Gray{Float64}(0.1)  Gray{Float64}(0.15)  Gray{Float64}(0.2)
 Gray{Float64}(0.1)   Gray{Float64}(0.2)  Gray{Float64}(0.3)   Gray{Float64}(0.4)
 Gray{Float64}(0.15)  Gray{Float64}(0.3)  Gray{Float64}(0.45)  Gray{Float64}(0.6)
 Gray{Float64}(0.2)   Gray{Float64}(0.4)  Gray{Float64}(0.6)   Gray{Float64}(0.8)
```

You can do window of even shape (here 2x2) with the following code:

```
julia> windows = mapwindow(collect, img, (0:1,0:1),border=Inner())
3×3 OffsetArray(::Matrix{Matrix{Gray{Float64}}}, 1:3, 1:3) with eltype Matrix{Gray{Float64}} with indices 1:3×1:3:
...
```

Lets see:

```
julia> windows[1,1] # top left
2×2 Array{Gray{Float64},2} with eltype Gray{Float64}:
 Gray{Float64}(0.05)  Gray{Float64}(0.1)
 Gray{Float64}(0.1)   Gray{Float64}(0.2)

julia> windows[2,2] # middle
2×2 Array{Gray{Float64},2} with eltype Gray{Float64}:
 Gray{Float64}(0.2)  Gray{Float64}(0.3)
 Gray{Float64}(0.3)  Gray{Float64}(0.45)

julia> windows[3,3] # bottom right
2×2 Array{Gray{Float64},2} with eltype Gray{Float64}:
 Gray{Float64}(0.45)  Gray{Float64}(0.6)
 Gray{Float64}(0.6)   Gray{Float64}(0.8)
```

Comment: I have been able to replicate the mapwindow implementation with the following function but I am unsure why the function "performs" faster than mapwindow? Consider the following function:
`function get_windows(matrix, window_size=8); X, Y = size(matrix); [@view matrix[j:j+window_size-1, i:i+window_size-1] for i in 1:X-window_size+1 for j in 1:Ywindow_size+1]; end`
This produces the same result as `vec(mapwindow(collect, img, (0:1, 0:1); border=Inner()))` but is much faster with less allocations. What am I missing here? Does it have something to do with views?

Comment: Yes, `collect` is allocating as it creates and materializes each submatrix. If you want to avoid allocations a matrix of views would be faster. However perhaps instead of `collect` you will provide some function that is actually doing something with the submatrix  - in that case this should good enough.